# How to upload a file to a hub site in SharePoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, document, file-upload, site, file

I've created a new app, generated app id and secret, assigned full permissions for https://mydomain.sharepoint.com , but I can't upload a file to the Shared Documents folder using the following PowerShell commands:

```
$SharePointURL = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com"
$SharePointDestPath = "/Shared Documents"
$file = "some-file"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SharePointURL -ClientId "asddsf-9999-4a88-8c79-ab8cabc67889" -ClientSecret "123343sdsfsdgfg2343434345656=" -WarningAction Ignore
Write-Host "done"
Write-Host "Uploading output file ... " -NoNewline
Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $SharePointDestPath
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

I'm getting 'access denied':

```
PS E:\sharepoint_online> .\script.ps1
Connecting to SharePoint online ... done
Uploading output file ... Add-PnPFile : Access denied.
At E:\sharepoint_online\script.ps1:26 char:1
+ Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $SharePointDestPath -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile
```

I'm probably doing something wrong or didn't make the proper settings. Can you please help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about other Libraries? Can you upload documents anywhere else?

Comment: Are you sure that you even can connect as you are supressing any errors you would receive trying to connect?